# Jboss fails after receiving a lot of queries using Jmeter

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x, jboss6.x, jboss5.x

During Stress/Load test and after sending so many queries using JMeter to my JBoss server, the server becomes irresponsive / unreachable. I want to know if there is any mechanism that makes JBoss unstable.

Answer (score 0):

This might be an issue with the threads, there might be some thread blocking or taking longer. On this case, you will need to get a thread dump, and verify where it's stuck/unresponsive. From the description it might a thread on JMeter that is using the resources and destabilizing JBoss. A server log could also show some issue as well.

## Recommendations

1. Get the thread dumps on the moment it happens
2. Analyze it with fastthread.io or other thread analyzer, e.g. TDA.
3. Verify any issue on the server.log

## Observation

For opening issues with JBoss 5/6/7 please update the logs and configuration files, this will make the debug easier.

-f